# Esoteric programming language in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have recently created an esoteric programming language called **01** and I will be grateful for a code review and any opinions or suggestions about the future of this language.

[GitHub](https://github.com/DeBos99/01)

```
require 'securerandom'
require 'optparse'

COMMANDS=['>','<','+','-','.',',','[',']','0','1']

ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED='Command "%s" not implemented in "%s".'
ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED='Language "%s" is not supported.'

def error(e)
    puts 'Error: %s'%e
    exit
end
def _012c(lang,id,count)
    case lang
        when 'raw'
            return id*count
        when 'brainfuck'
            case id
                when '>','<','+','-','.',',','[',']'
                    return id*count
                when '0'
                    return '[-]'
                else
                    error(ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED%[id,lang])
            end
        when 'c'
            case id
                when 'START'
                    return "#include<stdio.h>\nmain(){char d[30000],*p=d;"
                when '>'
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'p++;'
                    else
                        return "p+=#{count};"
                    end
                when '<'
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'p--;'
                    else
                        return "p-=#{count};"
                    end
                when '+'
                    if count==1 then
                        return '(*p)++;'
                    else
                        return "(*p)+=#{count};"
                    end
                when '-'
                    if count==1 then
                        return '(*p)--;'
                    else
                        return "(*p)-=#{count};"
                    end
                when '.'
                    return 'putchar(*p);'*count
                when ','
                    if count<=2 then
                        return 'scanf(\" %c\",&p);'*count
                    else
                        return "for(int i=0;i<#{count};i++)scanf(\" %c\",p);"
                    end
                when '['
                    return 'while(*p){'*count
                when ']'
                    return '}'*count
                when '0'
                    return '*p=0;'
                when '1'
                    return 'p=d[0];'
                when 'END'
                    return '}'
                else
                    error(ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED%[id,lang])
            end
        when 'c++'
            case id
                when 'START'
                    return "#include <iostream>\nmain(){char d[30000],*p=d;"
                when '>'
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'p++;'
                    else
                        return "p+=#{count};"
                    end
                when '<'
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'p--;'
                    else
                        return "p-=#{count};"
                    end
                when '+'
                    if count==1 then
                        return '(*p)++;'
                    else
                        return "(*p)+=#{count};"
                    end
                when '-'
                    if count==1 then
                        return '(*p)--;'
                    else
                        return "(*p)-=#{count};"
                    end
                when '.'
                    if count==1 then
                        return "std::cout<<*p;"
                    else
                        return "std::cout<<std::string(#{count},*p);"
                    end
                when ','
                    if count<=2 then
                        return 'std::cin>>*p;'*count
                    else
                        return "for(int i=0;i<#{count};i++)std::cin>>*p;"
                    end
                when '['
                    return 'while(*p){'*count
                when ']'
                    return '}'*count
                when '0'
                    return '*p=0;'
                when '1'
                    return 'p=d[0];'
                when 'END'
                    return '}'
                else
                    error(ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED%[id,lang])
            end
        when 'ruby'
            case id
                when 'START'
                    return 'd=[0]*30000;p=0;'
                when '>'
                    return "p+=#{count};"
                when '<'
                    return "p-=#{count};"
                when '+'
                    return "d[p]+=#{count};"
                when '-'
                    return "d[p]-=#{count};"
                when '.'
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'print d[p].chr;'
                    else
                        return "print d[p].chr*#{count};"
                    end
                when ','
                    if count==1 then
                        return 'd[p]=gets.ord;'
                    elsif count==2 then
                        return 'gets;d[p]=gets.ord;'
                    else
                        return "#{count-1}.times{gets};d[p]=gets.ord;"
                    end
                when '['
                    return 'while d[p]>0;'*count
                when ']'
                    return 'end;'*count
                when '0'
                    return 'd[p]=0;'
                when '1'
                    return 'p=0;'
                when 'END'
                    return ''
            end
        else
            error(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED%lang)
    end
end
def _012(input,output,lang)
    id=0
    last=''
    count=0
    File.open(output,'w') do |f2|
        f2<<_012c(lang,'START',0)
        File.open(input,'r') do |f|
            while not f.eof?
                c=f.read(1)
                if c=='0' then
                    if last=='1' then
                        f2<<_012c(lang,COMMANDS[id],count)
                        count=1
                    end
                    id+=id==COMMANDS.length-1?-id:1
                elsif c=='1' then
                    if c==last or count==0 then
                        count+=1
                    end
                end
                last=c
            end
            if last=='1' then
                f2<<_012c(lang,COMMANDS[id],count)
                count=1
            end
        end
        f2<<_012c(lang,'END',0)
    end
end
def _201(input,output)
    last=0
    File.open(input,'r') do |f|
        File.open(output,'w') do |f2|
            while not f.eof?
                c=f.read(1)
                if not COMMANDS.include?(c) then
                    next
                end
                i=COMMANDS.index(c)
                if last<=i then
                    f2<<'0'*(i-last)
                else
                    f2<<'0'*(COMMANDS.length-last+i)
                end
                f2<<'1'
                last=i
            end
        end
    end
end
def minify(input,output)
    pipe=SecureRandom.hex(32)
    _012(input,pipe,'raw')
    _201(pipe,output)
    File.delete(pipe)
end

OptionParser.new do |parser|
    options={}
    parser.on('-i','--input INPUT','Set INPUT file for program'){|x|options[:input]=x}
    parser.on('-o','--output OUTPUT','Set OUTPUT file for program'){|x|options[:output]=x}
    parser.on('-m', '--minify', 'Minify INPUT and get result in OUTPUT') do |x|
        if not options[:input] or not options[:output] then
            raise OptionParser::MissingArgument
        end
        minify(options[:input],options[:output])
    end
    parser.on('-c', '--convert LANG', 'Convert *.zo file to other LANG file') do |x|
        if not options[:input] or not options[:output] then
            raise OptionParser::MissingArgument
        end
        _012(options[:input],options[:output],x)
    end
    parser.on('-g', '--generate', 'Convert *.tzo to *.zo file') do |x|
        if not options[:input] or not options[:output] then
            raise OptionParser::MissingArgument
        end
        _201(options[:input],options[:output])
    end
end.parse!
```